# getting error while executing ansible command

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts, ansible-template, ansible-awx

I'm getting the following output when running an Ansible ping command:

```
[root@test1~]# ansible -m ping 10.95.252.140`
[WARNING]: Found both group and host with same name: dev_oip_servers

[WARNING]: Unable to load the facts cache plugin       
(namespace.collection_name.cache_plugin_name).

[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: 10.95.252.140

[WARNING]: No hosts matched, nothing to do
```

Answer (score 0):

> [WARNING]: Found both group and host with same name: dev_oip_servers

What result would you expect from `ansible -m ping dev_oip_servers` right now? Would it ping the host with that name or the host(s) in the group with that name? Or both? Rename either the host or group to avoid this ambiguity.

> [WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring:
>   10.95.252.140
>
> [WARNING]: No hosts matched, nothing to do

You need to make Ansible aware of 10.95.252.140 by adding it to your inventory. Refer to the [official documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#hosts-and-groups).

> [WARNING]: Unable to load the facts cache plugin
>   (namespace.collection_name.cache_plugin_name).

Please post the output of: `grep fact_caching /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg`

(adjust the path to ansible.cfg if necessary)